# Is there any way to work simultaneously on the same DAW project remotely?

Tags: recording, daw, cubase

Is there any way to work simultaneously on the same DAW project remotely?

Imagine the situation. My bandmate is sitting in another town (or even country) and have his DAW (say, Cubase) open and ready. Me, sitting here at home and recording some stuff using the very same project, so my friend can see all the newly recorded parts more or less on the fly — let's skip live monitoring for a while.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution for such use-case? I am thinking of putting the project to shared Dropbox folder which will be synced on save, but considering Cubase projects are pretty much depend on plugin environment, it could be really challenging to make project work identically on several machines, but probably other DAWs are more suitable for such task?

Comment: > I am thinking of putting the project to shared Dropbox folder which will be synced on save If the files will be available after sync, after project save, what exactly do you mean by >Is there any way to work simultaneously on the same DAW project remotely? If the goal is to just see what the one recording, or using the daw, is actually doing, you could use any screen sharing app. But I think you're talking about something more complex? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Personally I don’t even know if that’s possible between two different computers in the same room.

Comment: > But I think you're talking about something more complex?
Basically I want both side have the most actual version of the project, e.g. to listen closely to newly recorded phrase. Screen sharing will obviously rip the quality.

Answer (score 5):

Steinberg have two 'remote' working solutions, [VST Connect](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/vst_connect/start.html) & the new [VST Transit](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/vst_transit.html)

I haven't used either in my real workflow, but was involved in early betas of Connect, which at the time looked very promising.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for: https://www.bandlab.com/

I've never used it myself, but from what I gather it's sort of like Google Docs, only it's a DAW.  (Google DAW?)

Comment: This is definitely cool option, especially considering it's free. You can do collab recording and then just download all the tracks to put them back to your favorite DAW. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Share your desktop with him/her (VNC or similar), many (most/all) allow you to swap control back and forth.

Comment: That's of course a way to go, but I would rather prefer quality of project synced fully across two machines in, say, 5 seconds than mediocre quality of realtime RDP/VNC.